# How to increase performance when randomly selecting clusters and adding observations?

Tags: r, for-loop, coding-efficiency, data-generation

In a clustered dataset, I want to randomly pick some clusters and then add some simulated observations to the selected clusters. Then I want to create a dataset that combines the simulated and original observations from the selected clusters with all the original observations from the unselected clusters. I would also like to repeat this process many times and thus create many (maybe 1000) new datasets. I managed to do this using `for` loop but would like to know if there is any more efficient and concise way to accomplish this. Here is an example dataset:

```
## simulate some data
y <- rnorm(20)
x <- rnorm(20)
z <- rep(1:5, 4)
w <- rep(1:4, each=5)
dd <- data.frame(id=z, cluster=w, x=x, y=y)
#    id cluster           x           y
# 1   1       1  0.30003855  0.65325768
# 2   2       1 -1.00563626 -0.12270866
# 3   3       1  0.01925927 -0.41367651
# 4   4       1 -1.07742065 -2.64314895
# 5   5       1  0.71270333 -0.09294102
# 6   1       2  1.08477509  0.43028470
# 7   2       2 -2.22498770  0.53539884
# 8   3       2  1.23569346 -0.55527835
# 9   4       2 -1.24104450  1.77950291
# 10  5       2  0.45476927  0.28642442
# 11  1       3  0.65990264  0.12631586
# 12  2       3 -0.19988983  1.27226678
# 13  3       3 -0.64511396 -0.71846622
# 14  4       3  0.16532102 -0.45033862
# 15  5       3  0.43881870  2.39745248
# 16  1       4  0.88330282  0.01112919
# 17  2       4 -2.05233698  1.63356842
# 18  3       4 -1.63637927 -1.43850664
# 19  4       4  1.43040234 -0.19051680
# 20  5       4  1.04662885  0.37842390

cl <- split(dd, dd$cluster)  ## split the data based on clusters 
k <- length(dd$id)
l <- length(cl)
```

```
`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)  ## define "not in" to exclude unselected clusters so
                             ## as to retain their original observations
```

A `clsamp` function in the following code is then created which includes two `for` loops. The first `for` loop is to exclude the unselected clusters and the second `for` loop is to simulate new observations and append them to the selected clusters. Note that I randomly sample 2 clusters (10% of the total number of observations), without replacement

```
clsamp <- function(cl, k) {
  a <- sample(cl, size=0.1*k, replace=FALSE)  
  jud <- (names(cl) %notin% names(a))  
  need <- names(cl)[jud] 
  T3 <- NULL
  for (k in need) {
    T3 <- rbind(T3, cl[[k]])  
  }
  subt <- NULL
  s <- a
  for (j in 1:2) {
    y <- rnorm(2)
    x <- rnorm(2)
    d <- cbind(id=nrow(a[[j]]) + c(1:length(x)), 
               cluster=unique(a[[j]]$cluster), x, y)
    s[[j]] <- rbind(a[[j]], d)
    subt <- rbind(subt, s[[j]])
  }
  T <- rbind(T3, subt)
  return(T)
}
```

Finally, this creates a list of 5 datasets each of which combines the simulated and original observations from the selected clusters with all the original observations from the unselected clusters

```
Q <- vector(mode="list", length=5)
for (i in 1:length(Q)) {
  Q[[i]] <- clsamp(cl, 20)
}
```

Anyone knows a shorter way to do this? Maybe use the `replicate` function? Thanks.

Comment: Could you show how you use `clsamp`? I just get one 24x4 dataset.

Comment: The last chunk of code at the bottom of my post is to repeat `clsmap´ 5 times

Comment: Yes I discovered it in the `for` loop, thx! Please see my solution below and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This generates a sizeX2 matrix of random values and `cbind`s sampled cluster names and consecutive ids to it. It directly starts with `dd` and also works when you convert `dd` to a matrix `mm`, which might be slightly faster. Output is a data frame, though. Instead of your `k` I use `f` to directly calculate the number of rows that should be added to the two selected clusters. In case the size gets zero, the original data frame is returned.

```
clsamp2 <- function(m, f=.1) {
  size <- round(nrow(m)*f)
  if (size == 0) as.data.frame(m)
  else {
    ids <- unique(m[,1])
    cls <- unique(m[,2])
    rd <- matrix(rnorm(size * 4), ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("x", "y")))
    out <- rbind.data.frame(m, cbind(id=rep(max(ids) + 1:size, each=2), 
                                     cluster=sample(cls, 2), rd))
    `rownames<-`(out[order(out$cluster, out$id), ], NULL)
  }
}
```

#### Result

```
set.seed(42)  ## same seed also used for creating `dd`
clsamp2(dd, .1)

## or
mm <- as.matrix(dd)
clsamp2(mm, .1)

#    id cluster           x           y
# 1   1       1 -0.30663859  1.37095845
# 2   2       1 -1.78130843 -0.56469817
# 3   3       1 -0.17191736  0.36312841
# 4   4       1  1.21467470  0.63286260
# 5   5       1  1.89519346  0.40426832
# 6   1       2 -0.43046913 -0.10612452
# 7   2       2 -0.25726938  1.51152200
# 8   3       2 -1.76316309 -0.09465904
# 9   4       2  0.46009735  2.01842371
# 10  5       2 -0.63999488 -0.06271410
# 11  6       2  1.37095845  0.40426832
# 12  7       2  0.36312841  1.51152200
# 13  1       3  0.45545012  1.30486965
# 14  2       3  0.70483734  2.28664539
# 15  3       3  1.03510352 -1.38886070
# 16  4       3 -0.60892638 -0.27878877
# 17  5       3  0.50495512 -0.13332134
# 18  1       4 -1.71700868  0.63595040
# 19  2       4 -0.78445901 -0.28425292
# 20  3       4 -0.85090759 -2.65645542
# 21  4       4 -2.41420765 -2.44046693
# 22  5       4  0.03612261  1.32011335
# 23  6       4 -0.56469817 -0.10612452
# 24  7       4  0.63286260 -0.09465904
```

To create the list of five samples, you may use `replicate`.

```
replicate(5, clsamp2(dd, .1), simplify=FALSE)
```

Running time is negligible.

```
system.time(replicate(1000, clsamp2(dd, .1), simplify=FALSE))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.44    0.03    0.44
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. Why do you need to calculate the size: `size <- round(nrow(m)*f)` and have the condition: `if (size == 0) as.data.frame(m)`?

Comment: You're welcome @cliu ! Actually the size is calculated similarly to your original code `size=0.1*k`—the `nrow` of the data frame is the same as the `length` of a column, right? I just changed the arguments, so you now may define the percentage directly in the function. The `if (size == 0) checks if you don't want to sample any rows for some reason, and returns the input data (`as.data.frame` just because you may also input a `matrix`), because the rest of the could would fail if `size == 0`.

Comment: Nice! This even allows greater flexibility for specifying sampling probability in the function itself and so it is better than my original function.

Comment: @cliu Sorry for that! ;)